# Is it possible to let users without any role see a homepage?

Tags: roles, servicenow

I would love to let some of my users see a homepage without them having any role. I thought I can specify a homepage in the user preferences, but I didn't manage to do that.
Is it even possible to have view access to a homepage without having any role in SNOW?

Answer (score 1):

There is a role called "public", try using that with the home page you are wanting to show these users. There are also portal pages and CMS sites which for sure can be viewable without login

Comment: Will I have to pay any license cost for these users? Or are they still free?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what they will be doing. In our set up, it's just the performers that require a license (user with the itil role). We have people approving requests (approvers) and that doesn't require a license in our agreement with SN. So a user that is simply going to get help, request things, get information likely isn't going to need a license (role).